# Linker Error for templated Class with friend functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, friend

I'm trying to recreat a stack with a forward_list. However, i use friend functions to overload the + and << operator.

```
#pragma once
#include <forward_list>
template <class T> class Stack;

template <class T>
Stack<T> operator+(const Stack<T> &a, const Stack<T> &b){
//implementation
}

template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, Stack<T> &s)
{
//implementation
}

template <class T>
class Stack
{
friend Stack<T> operator+(const Stack<T> &a, const Stack<T> &b);
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, Stack<T> &s);
std::forward_list<T> l;
public:
//Some public functions
};
```

For both of the friend functions i get an linker Error , when i try to call them in my main like:

```
int main(){
  Stack<int> st;
  st.push(4);
  Stack<int> st2;
  st2.push(8);
  cout<<st + st2<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Stack<int> __cdecl operator+(class Stack<int> const &,class Stack<int> const &)" (??H@YA?AV?$Stack@H@@ABV0@0@Z) referenced in function _main
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Stack<int> &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$Stack@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you have implemented the `operator +` for your `Stack` class? In some .CPP file?

Comment: any particular reason why you want to use friends at all?

Comment: @Ajay no it's implementd in the header, where the //implementation substitute is in the code above.

Comment: @HolgerKretzschmar in terms of practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template friend declarations within the Stack class are not quite correct. You need to declare like this:

```
template<class T>
friend Stack<T> operator+(const Stack<T> &a, const Stack<T> &b);

template<class T>
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, Stack<T> &s);
```

Since you are using MSVC, please [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1b2td24.aspx) Microsoft documentation for further reference.